# Batch Geocode using Axios

Tags: here-api

Testing the HERE Batch GeoCode life-cycle through node application. We have similar working with Azure Mappings but they are crazy expensive.

Seems as if the initial post request is succeeding. But is stuck on "submitted" status during status check. And failing during result check with 404. Using axius to make the queries - with the documented examples.

```
const getStatus = async requestId => {
    const url = statusURL(requestId);
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    const response = res.data.Response;
    return response;
};

const getResult = async requestId => {
    const url = resultURL(requestId);
    const config = { headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/plain' } };
    const res = await axios.get(url, config);
    const response = res.data.Response;
    return response;
};

const requestGeo = async input => {
    const url = requestURL;
    const res = await axios.post(url, input, {
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/plain' },
    });
    const requestId = res.data.Response.MetaInfo.RequestId;
    return requestId;
};

getStatus(requestId)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });


const input = `recId|street|city|postalCode|country 
1|425 Randolph St|Chicago||USA 
2|31 St James Ave|Boston|02116|USA 
3|Invalidenstrasse 117|Berlin|10115|DEU`;

requestGeo(input)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the "&action=run" parameter in your initial request, then the job is being checked, stored and set as "submitted". This does not mean that it will be executed.

Alternatively you can send an "action=start"-request to start the job.

Having applied one of these two options, the job will be scheduled for execution and flagged as "accepted".